# How to use JWT in localstorage to keep a user logged in?

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, jwt, mern

I've created a react application with a MongoDB/Express backend API. I've also stored the JWT token inside of localStorage, however, I do not know how to use the JWT to keep the user logged in, I don't see the connection between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how are you checking if the user is logged in or not in your application, if your login includes checking the JWT from the state, then you should load the JWT from the local storage and put it in the application state when the application starts.

This is an example that gets the token from the local storage when the application store is initialized:

```
const initialState = {
  auth: {
    authToken: localStorage.getItem('token')
  }
};

const store = createStore(
  appReducers,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(appLogger, reduxThunk)
);
```